# opencv didn't output images correctly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have debugging my code and here is what I found:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = (img / 127.5) - 1

cv2.imshow("img",(127.5*(img+1)).astype(int))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

these operations don't output the same picture even tough they are same, does somebody konow why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the `dtype` each time you display:

```
print(img.dtype)
```