# why does cv2.imwrite method write a black square for a mnist test image dataset?

Tags: python, opencv, mnist

I am trying to .imwrite one of the MNIST test images with openCV but it shows just a black square. I don't get why!!

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import mnist
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import cv2

train_images = mnist.train_images()
train_labels = mnist.train_labels()
test_images = mnist.test_images()
test_labels = mnist.test_labels()

# Normalize the images.
train_images = (train_images / 255) - 0.5
test_images = (test_images / 255) - 0.5
print(train_images.shape)
#print(test_images.shape)
img = cv2.imwrite( "img.jpg", test_images[0])
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63371964/2836621

Comment: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'dtype' , BUT I don't get why!

Comment: `imwrite()` will save a **Numpy uint8/16 array** as a JPEG/PNG.

Comment: Have you tried saving the images before the normalisation? I think the problem might come from there, since you normalize the pixels between [-0.5, 0.5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by others, you are trying to save a normalized image in the domain [-0.5, 0.5] which previously was in the domain [0, 255]. `cv2.imwrite` does not support this. Here's the official help:

> The function imwrite saves the image to the specified file. The image
> format is chosen based on the filename extension (see imread() for the
> list of extensions). Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case
> of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’
> channel order) images can be saved using this function

Save your image before normalization or undo it like this:

`img = cv2.imwrite( "img.jpg", (test_images[0] + 0.5) * 255)`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is right, but the correction is not:

```py
img = cv2.imwrite('img.jpg', (test_images[0] * 255 + 0.5).astype('int'))
```